# Installing Wing IDE on Kali Linux 2.0

Tags: python, kali-linux, ide

I am currently reading the book 'Black Hat Python', and am having a problem installing Wing IDE on Kali Linux. Please do help me out!

[image: Snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the output in your terminal that your are trying to install the 64-bit version of Wing IDE.
But when I look at the file manager I can see that you have downloaded the 32-bit version.

As the terminal output states, it cannot find the file you have specified (wingide5_5.1.8-1_amd64.deb).

Try running this command instead:

```
dpkg -i ~/Downloads/wingide5_5.1.8-1_i386.deb
```

/J